# Which is the best way to manage binary data from Fortran to python?

Tags: python, fortran, fortran90

I would like to start managing my Fortran data using the power of python.
In Fortran90, it's straightforward to write the results in binary. For
instance, I save an array in a binary file and I would like to read it and
do some statistics in python.
What is the correct way of doing this?

Comment: Use [NumPy](http://www.numpy.org/) for number crunching in Python.

Comment: @larsmans: Your comment appears irrelevant. OP is asking about how to go about reading Fortran "binary" data into Python, not how to process said data.

Comment: @KyleKanos: NumPy also has facilities for I/O and interop with Fortran libraries.

Comment: @larsmans: I know it does, but your comment was about "number crunching" not file IO, hence the claim it is irrelevant.

Comment: @KyleKanos: "... and do some statistics in Python", so I suggested the all-in-one solution.

Comment: @larsmans: Again, your initial comment has nothing to do with file IO that the OP is asking for. You are trying to recover a battle you lost 2 hours ago, please stop and admit (to yourself, I don't care for a reply) your comment was irrelevant.

Answer (score 1):

The module [fortranfile](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/fortranfile) offers a very convenient way of reading binary Fortran files. Requires [numpy](http://www.numpy.org/).

Answer (score 0):

This page may help: http://stromberg.dnsalias.org/~strombrg/converting-binary.html

In short, binary data is best avoided, but the page still talks about ways of dealing with it.